# Package exercise: change "exercise" to French "exercice"

Tags: french, exercises

I am preparing a homework for my students with LaTeX, so I used `\usepackage{exercise}`. In the `.pdf` file I got "exercise" and I want it to be in French (exercice) not English.

I put `\usepackage[french]{babel}` but nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Exercise}[title=...]

\Question{....}

\end{Exercise}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercise package with Babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306046/exercise-package-with-babel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [`exercise`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise) documentation (§5.2), you can see how the text "constants" (e.g. *List of exercises*, *Exercise*, *Answer of exercise*, ...) are defined. It is done through following macros, respectively:

```
\def\listexercisename{List of exercises}%
\def\ExerciseName{Exercise}%
\def\AnswerName{Answer of exercise}%
...
```

Thus, you can use following macro to adapt them according to your needs:

```
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercice}
```

However, for some languages (spanish, italian, dutch... and french), Paul Pichaureau (creator of this package) already did this work. This should be done automatically when you load a language in `babel`; but how?
 You can see (in the same paragraph), that `exercise` recognise the language loaded via this command: `\@ifpackageloaded{babel}{\addto{\captions<LANGUAGE>}{...`.

<s>In the case of french language, the command is: `\addto{\captionsfrenchb}{`, thus you should load the `frenchb` option (and not `french`) of `babel`-package to make `exercise` automatically translate macros in french.</s> → if this works for most languages (at least `spanish`, `dutch`, and `italian`), it now doesn't seem to work with neither `french`, nor `frenchb`.

---

**TL;DR:** To translate the names in french, you have <s>two</s> one solution<s>s</s>:

- translate each of them manually via `\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Nouveau nom de mes exercices}`-like commands.
- <s>load the `frenchb` option in `babel` (and not the `french` one): already implemented translations will be automatically used;</s>

---

**Edit:** With most recent (i.e. post TeXlive 2012) LaTeX distro, neither `frenchb` nor `french` options in `babel` seem to work with automated translation of `exercice` package (cf. [Exercise package with Babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306046/exercise-package-with-babel/306048)). You should then copy-paste these lines into your `.tex` files to emulate the translation:

```
\renewcommand\listexercisename{Liste des exercices}%
\renewcommand\ExerciseName{Exercice}%
\renewcommand\AnswerName{Solution de l'exercice}%
\renewcommand\ExerciseListName{Ex.}%
\renewcommand\AnswerListName{Solution}%
\renewcommand\ExePartName{Partie}%
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @Bernard good catch: I actually tried it... but with another language than french(b). my bad! See similar issue on [Exercise package with Babel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306046/64454).

Comment: \renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercice} works fine with me ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest perhaps: line 74 of `exercise.sty`, replace `addto{\captionsfrenchb}` with `addto{\captionsfrench}`.